# kohana, what does stop accessing files directly from URL mean?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

You should recognize the first tag as an opening php tag (if you don't you should probably learn php). What follows is a small check that makes sure that this file is being included by Kohana. It stops people from accessing files directly from the url.

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/tutorials/hello-world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your webservers DocumentRoot is `/srv/www` and you put your example code under `/srv/www/application/classes/controller/hello.php`.

`"stop accessing files directly from URL"` means that if a user now navigates to `www.example.com/application/classes/controller/hello.php` it will not run the script, instead it will display 'No Direct Script Access', since `SYSPATH` is not defined.

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/flow